# Instantiate working WebView in AndroidTestCase

Tags: android, testing, webview

I have a testcase in which I would like to test our JavaScript-Callbacks in conjunction with a real WebView.

I get no exceptions but loading data into the view (or executing javascript) does not work.

Here is a simplified (failing) example in which I'd like to verify I can load some content into the WebView:

```
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class JavascriptCallbacksIntegrationTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        webView = new WebView(getContext());
    }

    public void testStuff() {
        webView.loadData("<html><head><title>hello</title></head></html>", "text/html", "utf-8");
        assertEquals("hello", webView.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the part

> webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
>
> //, right after adding
>
> webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: Doing this the testcase still fails, I cannot load data into the view.